# How to change elements display order in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am having a trouble showing the elements in my page

I have elements like

```
<img src='test1.jpg'>
<div>
<a href='#'>change</a>
</div>

<img src='test2.jpg'>
<div>
<a href='#'>change</a>
</div>

<img src='test3.jpg'>
<div>
<a href='#'>change</a>
</div>

<img src='test4.jpg'>
<div>
<a href='#'>change</a>
</div>

<img src='test5.jpg'>
<div>
<a href='#'>change</a>
</div>

<img src='test6.jpg'>
<div>
<a href='#'>change</a>
</div>
```

The images are adding to the dom by DB record and I want to add the <`div`>with change <`a`> tag for every images to give
the user an option to do things (like change image source). All my `div` have css like

```
display: block;
float: right;
```

and images have

```
display: inline-block;
```

My problem is that

the images and the div are in the wrong order.

for example:

```
img1 img2 img3 img4 img5 img6        div6  div5 div4 div3 div2 div1
```

clicking `div6` will change `img6` property.

This is the correct order I need

```
img1 img2 img3 img4 img5 img6        div1  div2 div3 div4 div5 div6
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think of floating elements as they are pushing to a stack. If you want the divs to appear like

***div1 div2 div3***

then you have to push it to the dom in that order

***div3 div2 div1***

But, the easier and the more common way to do it, is to use **jQuery** to get the index of the clicked div  and apply the changes on the image that has the same index. Here is an example that will hide the image on clicking the corresponding div:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $("img:eq("+idx+")").hide(); //change that to whatever operation you want to do on the image
});
```

---

This might be useful:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq
- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: My problem is that I can't push those div in reverse order because all the images are built from DB and the divs will be attached to each images in the same order. I was hoping if there is a quick css fix for this issue. +1 though.

Comment: @FlyingCat I think their is no direct css hack to do that. Your best bet is to include all the divs to a `float:right` container and make the divs `float:left`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the placement/user interaction is ideal, but if you really want the `img`s arranged on the left and in order, and the `div`s arranged on the right and in order...

Put the `div`s in a container div and style it with `float: right`.

You shouldn't need any extra styling; the smaller `div`s do not need `display` or `float` specified, and `img` doesn't need `display` specified.